# Postgres regex matching - match a character OR nothing

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am trying to get the domain name in Postgres using a regex.

When I do:

```
select substring('http://yahoo.com' from 'http://(.+?)/|');
```

it returns the empty string.
I want it to return http://yahoo.com

It works if I do the below, but not all urls end with a trailing slash.

```
select substring('http://yahoo.com/' from 'http://(.+?)/|');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write:

```
select substring('http://yahoo.com' from 'http://[^/]+/?');
```

which will match `http://`, plus the domain (all characters besides `/`), plus a trailing `/` if present.

(Disclaimer: not tested.)

Comment: It seems to work, but any idea how to make it extract 'yahoo.com' if the string is http:// www.yahoo.com ? I just want the main domain name, not the subdomain

Comment: Wait, your original question said you wanted it to return `http://yahoo.com`; are you saying you actually want *just* the `yahoo.com` part, not the `http://` part?

Comment: Also -- how do you propose to identify the "main domain name"? For example, with `http://www.amazon.co.uk/` I assume the "main domain name" is `amazon.co.uk` (last three segments), but with `http://foo.bar.ib.com/` I assume it's `ib.com` (last two).

Answer (score -1):

```
select substring('http://yahoo.com' from 'http://(.+?)/?|');
```

Notice the `?` after the last `/` that means it is optional.

Comment: That won't work: `.+?` is non-greedy, so if you don't require it to be followed by something, then it will choose to match just one character.